# HTML/CSS/JS Images are not loading Online

Tags: javascript, html, css, http-status-code-404, hosting

The images for a section of my site is not loading when I upload the files. When I check them locally everything works fine. I get this error code in the js console.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

This only happens to six images in the same section. All the other images load up just fine. I have checked the path and that does not seem to be the issue. I added three 300x200 images as an example and kept 3 images the same.

```css
/*------ Basic Setup ------*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.clearfix {
  zoom: 1
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: '.';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.row {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/*------ Dividers ------*/

.divider {
  width: 25%;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(89, 89, 89, 0.65);
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
}

.divider span {
  font-size: 200%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 10px;
}


/*------ Team Section ------*/

.team {
  background-color: white;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
}

.team-content {
  color: grey;
  text-align: center;
}

.team h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.team .description {
  margin-top: -2.5%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
}

.team-pics {
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.team-content p {
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <!--Favicon-->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="images/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
  <link rel="manifest" href="images/favicons/manifest.json">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="images/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
  <!--Favicon-->
</head>

<body>
  <section class="team" id="team">
    <div class="team-content">
      <h1>Our Team</h1>
      <div class="divider d2">
        <span><i class="fa fa-paw" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 description">
        <p>The German Shepherd Foundation is comprised of people with so much passion for German Shepherds.</p>
        <p>You will not find any other orginazation with our passion and expertise.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row team-pics">
        <div class="col-xs-6 .col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <img src="images/john.jpg" alt="John" class="img-responsive">
          <p>Founder - John</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 .col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <img src="images/sam.jpg" alt="Sam" class="img-responsive">
          <p>Head of Puppy Care - Sam</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 .col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <img src="images/adam.jpg" alt="Adam" class="img-responsive">
          <p>Veterinarian - Adam</p>
        </div>


        <div class="col-xs-6 .col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <img src="http://www.pestworld.org/media/1030/300x200.gif" alt="Blair" class="img-responsive">
          <p>Transtion Specialist - Blair</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 .col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <img src="http://www.pestworld.org/media/1030/300x200.gif" alt="Jack" class="img-responsive">
          <p>Grooming Expert - Jack</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 .col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <img src="http://www.pestworld.org/media/1030/300x200.gif" alt="Tammy" class="img-responsive">
          <p>Dietitian - Tammy</p>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 description">
        <br><br><br>
        <p>Intrested in joining our crack team of dog experts?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This isn't really the actual src, is it? -> src="images/john.jpg"

Comment: Double check the URLs again. Check if it's not `"/images/sam.jpg"` instead of `"images/sam.jpg"`.

Comment: Here is what the original looks like http://prntscr.com/e9c8s3

Comment: And what it looks like locally http://prntscr.com/e9c94r

Comment: Provide us the link of your online Website/Host please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue. The source image capitalization was the issue.

Wrong
Source Image Name: john (jpeg)
Code: img src="images/John.jpg" alt="John">

Correct
Source Image Name: John (jpeg)
Code: img src="images/John.jpg" alt="John">

Weird that it works only locally like that but not online.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the access settings of the images folder and its contents.
You probably need to set read access to all on the server where it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is every thing perfect but the only problem is in img tag. See below -

```html
<img src="Specific Path" alt="John">
```

You give wrong path for 
Founder - John

Answer (score 0):

try using absolute adress to the image. define a constant with the base url of your site.
if your site is in php the you can do like this.

```
define('base_url','http://example.org/');
```

then use it with you images like this.

```
<img src="<?=base_url."absoulutepath/file.jpg"?>">
```

this is also a good choice as you need to define only once and you will always have correct path to file.